# Как сделать подсветку выбранного пункта меню если мы переходим глубже в меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery, меню

Имеется такое меню такого типа

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/laminat">Ламинат</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/santekhnika/vanni">Ванны</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/santekhnika/smesiteli">Смесители</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/santekhnika/unitazy">Унитазы</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/santekhnika/mebel-dlya-vannoj">Мебель</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/teplyj-pol">Теплый пол</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="/index.php/katalog/dekorativnye-paneli">Декор панели</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
  .active{  
    color:#f00;  
  }
</style>
```

и js

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.menu a').each(function() {
        if ('http://www.mysite.ru'+$(this).attr('href') == window.location.href)
        {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

    });
});
```

Все хорошо работает, НО если мы переходим глубже, к примеру в

```
/index.php/katalog/laminat/002-dub-vaddenze
```

подсветка пункта "Ламинат" пропадает. Как изменить js что бы подсветка не пропадала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('document').ready(function() { 
  $('.menu a').each(function() { 
    var link = 'http://www.mysite.ru'+$(this).attr('href');
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(link) !== -1){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!)